# 0x Websocket on ropsten

Tags: 0x

I try to use it on ropsten testnet with below code but i never get any message from the server. Does 0x websocket not support ropsten, or is anything wrong in my code?
const socket = W3CWebSocket('wss://ropsten.api.0x.org/sra/v4')

```
const msg = {
    "type": "subscribe",
    "channel": "orders",
    "makerToken" : "0xc778417e063141139fce010982780140aa0cd5ab",
    "takerToken" : "0x1f9840a85d5af5bf1d1762f925bdaddc4201f984",
    "requestId": "123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426655440000"
  }
  socket.onopen = () => {
    console.log('Web socket client connected');
    socket.send(JSON.stringify(msg));
  }
  
  socket.onmessage = ({data}) => {
    console.log('msg from server', data)
  }
```

Thanks a lot for your support

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your question :) The 0x Websocket API currently only supports mainnet. Your code works fine for `'wss://api.0x.org/sra/v4'`.